# How to control a Flutter/Flare animation based on timer?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to accomplish the following:
Based on a variable timer (hours, minutes and seconds) three goals have to be fulfilled: Received, Preparing and Ready.

Example: when the timer is about 15 seconds, the lines and the dot have to be filled with the orange color -- just in a linear way.

So far, I have accomplished this:

[image]

Where:

- The first line is made with Flutter **CustomPainter**
- The second line is made with **Flare**, see:https://www.2dimensions.com/a/JohanWalhout/files/flare/fill-line/embed

Now, I'm facing the follow problems:

- How can I animate the Flutter **CustomPainter** like the Flare animation?

or:

- How can I animate the Flare animation where the animation duration is the time it takes to fill the orange color?

Please, see the complete app in the following repo: https://github.com/LiveLikeCounter/Flutter-Food-Delivery

Answer (score 1):

Flare and CustomPainter are two completely different things. CustomPainter is a widget that comes with the Flutter SDK and Flare is an vector animation tool by 2Dimensions. They cannot change/manipulate each other in any way.

> How can I animate the Flare animation where the animation duration is
>   the time it takes to fill the orange color?

If you want to stick to Flare then you can separately create the fill animation and use `FlareController` to play the animation as and when you wish.

Just remember the name you give it [e.g In this case, it is 'home-on' and 'home-off'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emfXC.png)

Refer to this blog before you start to code/design:

> https://medium.com/2dimensions/building-a-responsive-house-with-flare-flutter-31af823ba805

However, it is still recommended that you use AnimationController and some variables to get full control of your widgets instead of relying on any third party animation tool.

Answer (score 0):

For the custom painter you can use a basic `canvas.drawLine` and make sure your shouldRepaint returns true when ever the end line position changed. The end position will be relative to the timer and what you consider a line to be full.

For the Flare animation you have to create a controller that will take in the time on every timer tick you want to animate, then set your current playback time for you artboard equal to the position you want for that time. 15second = 100% in your case so your applied time should be the full animationDuration, 7.5 you'll set it to animationDuration * 0.5, so you have to figure your formula out for that.

You can use my SwipeAdvanceController from [SmartFlare](https://pub.dev/packages/smart_flare) then call updateSwipePosition using Fake values that will represent your "swipe". The controller will advance from 0 to 100% of the animation depending on how you swipe over the animation allowing you to create sliders, etc using Flare so it should work with this by passing in fake touch positions to emulate.